# Why am I getting this error when building flutter app for windows?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I am trying to use my app as a windows desktop, but I get this error in the console:

```
Building Windows application...
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/native_pdf_renderer/windows/DownloadProject.cmake:179 (message):
Build step for pdfium failed: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/native_pdf_renderer/windows/CMakeLists.txt:16 (download_project)


Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

Tried to look for similar error but did not find something like this.

Comment: does it happen only for this project? Could be an issue on [`native_pdf_renderer`](https://pub.dev/packages/native_pdf_renderer)

Comment: see https://github.com/rbcprolabs/packages.flutter/issues/167#issuecomment-1031860282

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the pull request was merged, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/ScerIO/packages.flutter/issues/167#issuecomment-1031860282) as mentioned in the comment.

The only way to solve this is by adding the line

```
set(PDFIUM_VERSION "4634" CACHE STRING "")
```

into your **CMakeLists.txt** file as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ScerIO/packages.flutter/pull/233#issuecomment-970246427).

> @hillelcoren It seems that the upstream repository has cleared out
> some of the release artifacts we were using. I've opened a pull
> request [#241](https://github.com/ScerIO/packages.flutter/pull/241) to
> fix this but in the meantime you can also work around this by adding
>
> ```
> set(PDFIUM_VERSION "4634" CACHE STRING "")
> ```
>
> to your windows/cmakelists.txt file (you may need to run `flutter clean` after this).
>
> There is also the .zip vs .tgz issue that you've spotted but this only
> affects the most recent pdfium versions, I was waiting for their
> release process to stabilize before pushing a PR to address this.

Currently, the pull request have been merged and should resolve the issue relating to this.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command "Flutter doctor" and check whether you have visual studio build tool 16 2019.

flutter version 2.9 and later supports only visual studio build tool 17 2022.

upgrade your Visual Studio Build Tool version.